# Vim autocmd does not map properly a mapping

Tags: vim, file-type, autocmd

I want to create a plugin which maps a certain localleader mapping to a function call.

I have a ftplugin/javascript.vim file with the following content:

```
augroup javascript_pluginName
  au!
  echom "The plugin is loaded for JS"
  au FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>j :call pluginName#pluginName#funName()<cr>
augroup END
```

When I open a javascript file, the message is printed, but then checking the mapped combinations shows that there is no such mapping.

I understand, that nnoremap is simply not going to map on top of other mappings. However, if I only leave the nnoremap command, without putting it in an autocmd, it would map properly.
Simply executing the call in command mode also works fine.

I looked into the vim help to see how to use autocmd, and I can't see any difference between the way I use it and what is explained there. The "Learn Vim the Hard Way" book also didn't help.

Is there something I'm missing? Should I frame the autocmd somehow differently?

Comment: Have you tried `*.js` instead of `javascript`?

Comment: Hi @SergioAraujo yes, I tried it, but then I read that the FileType event does not work with file patterns but with the value of the "ft" setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem is!
Apparently, according to this article: https://vimways.org/2018/from-vimrc-to-vim/ if you put a filetype specific code into a filetype plugin, there is no need to create an autocmd for it.

The boilerplate is all made redundant by the general behaviour of vim setting the filetype on open and then running the ftplugin scripts, which are relevant for the file.

This means that in my ftplugin/javascript.vim file I only need the mapping:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>j :call pluginName#pluginName#funName()<cr>
```